# Starting out with OpenNI on a Mac

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, openni

So i'm beginning a project with a friend using the Xbox Kinect, and as we both use macs, we needed a good library, so we went with OpenNI because of it's APIs. To the problem : Trying to compile the samples after editing returns errors and ultimately a segmentation fault (11).

From gdb, the output is not that helpful, though it told me where the problem is, and thats it. Is there any way i can narrow the problem down further than this? If you need sample code of what i'm doing, ask.

`Program received signal EXC_BAD_ACCESS, Could not access memory.
Reason: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at address: 0x0000000000000000
0x00000001000f0221 in xnSetMapOutputMode ()
(gdb) backtrace
0  0x00000001000f0221 in xnSetMapOutputMode ()

1  0x0000000100004570 in main ()`